# std::move in function parameter will not use again?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I know if you use `std::move(s)`, **then the s can not use again**, But I have some questions.

If I don't do `move constructor/assignment operator`, Does the variable still exist?

```cpp
// not do assignment
void test2(string &&t) {
    return;
}

void test1(string &&s) {
    test2(std::move(s));
}

int main()
{
    string s("123");
    
    test1(std::move(s));
    cout << "s: " << s << endl;
}
```

Above test seems it exist, So is this the best practice to use std::move in a while loop below.

```cpp
// do assignment
bool test4(string &&t) {
    if (condition) {
        return false;
    }
    
    string m = std::move(t);
    
    return true;
}

void test3(string &&s) {
    while(true) {
        if( test4(std::move(s)) ) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

seems if you don't do `move assignment operator` the s is still exist next loop, when it success then it do `move assignment operator` and break the loop, There seems to be no logical error, but I want to know if this is the best practice ? Because you need to handle data carefully.

Comment: You can absolutely use `s` again. The object will however be in an undefined state, so there are some things you should not do with it.

Comment: Something to bear in mind as you continue your career in C++ is that you should never trust the output of a program to mean that a certain behavior is guaranteed.

Comment: What @AndyG means is learn about a certain condition (or more accurately, a behaviour) called [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a)

Comment: @super "undefined state" -> "unspecified state".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know if you use std::move(s), then the s can not use again

That's not really true.

After an object of a standard library type has been moved-from, unless otherwise stated its state is "valid but unspecified", so indeed it's best not to use it again unless you know you've put it back into a useful state (e.g. `.clear()` on a vector). (If the object is of one of your own types, *you* define those rules.)

But `std::move` doesn't move anything. It only prepares your expression for triggering a move. If that didn't occur, then literally nothing happened, and you can keep using `s` without fear.

However, you will confuse readers of your code. If you're not passing the result of `std::move(s)` to a move constructor or move assignment operator, best not write it at all.

> seems if you don't do move assignment operator the s is still exist next loop, when it success then it do move assignment operator and break the loop, There seems to be no logical error, but I want to know if this is the best practice ?

It's correct, but it's kind of hard to read and follow, so it might be best to find some clearer way to structure it.

> Because you need to handle data carefully.

Indeed.

---

Ideally, both `test1` and `test2` would take `const std::string&` (since neither of them take ownership of the string), and then it will also be clear to the author of `main` that they needn't/shouldn't write `std::move` there: it would be harmless, but pointless.

Comment: thx for your advice, but `Ideally, both test1 and test2 would take const std::string& (since neither of them take ownership of the string)` if I use an rvalue I need to `copy constructor`, if use rvalue reference then I use `move constructor `. If I don't want to use s again, because I already know what I do?

Comment: @dahohu527 Why? You're not moving from it. That's the crux of your question.

Comment: The ownership is the question, when I write some class like myString I really need to implement `move constructor `

Comment: @dahohu527 I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you are asking me.

Comment: My question is why you suggest to `test1 and test2 would take const std::string&`, I use `rvalue reference` beacuse I want to do `move assignment`

Comment: @dahohu527 But you _don't_ do move assignment!! `test1` passes it on to `test2`, and `test2` does nothing.

Comment: it's just a testcase. Thank you for the explanation！